# How to install wink?

Tags: recordmydesktop

I can't install wink by the following commands:

```
  sudo apt-get install wink
```

Here is the log

```
  sam@sam:~$ sudo apt-get install wink
  [sudo] password for sam: 
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Package wink is not available, but is referred to by another package.
  This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
  is only available from another source

  E: Package 'wink' has no installation candidate
```

1. What is 'referred to by another package'? Where is that package?
2. How to install wink?

The method using apt-get is the better than download from website.

Thank you~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the wink package is no longer available in the repositories of ubuntu since hardy

1. [Wink Package Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wink&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), This mean that the package is missing..
2. You have two option :

   - Find someone that have a PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) for your Ubuntu version. Search for wink package there..
   - Compiling from source.
3. [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: Why they want to remove it? Is there any better package than wink on latest ubuntu? Thank you~